# How to differentiate two time timeperiod between two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wanna know how to differentiate a time period in a day between two columns like in time and out time?

Comment: Have you seen the [`DATEDIFF()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
DATEDIFF (datepart , startdate , enddate)
```

The `datepart` you have mentioend in your question is `day`. You can use any of `day`, `d` and `dd`

**Sample**

```
DECLARE @inTime DATETIME, @outTime DATETIME
SET @inTime = '2015-05-01 12:10:09'
SET @outTime = '2015-05-22 05:15:36'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @inTime, @outTime) AS timedifferentiate
```

**In a query**

```
SELECT  ,inTime
        ,outTime
        DATEDIFF(DAY, inTime, outTime) AS timedifferentiate
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a minus operator, and convert to [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(time, -- Note the time datatype range is 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999
        CONVERT(datetime, '2015-04-01 19:03') -- Out time
        - CONVERT(datetime, '2015-04-01 09:02') -- In time
    ) TimeDiff
```